# Spring Data JPA existsBy projection for entity with @IdClass compound primary key doesn't set AbstractPersistable_id on query creation and fails

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, exists

I am attempting to write a spring-data-jpa repository existsBy() projection for an entity that has a compound primary key defined via @IdClass. However, when I try to add an existsBy() projection to the repository, the application fails to load application context due to a NullPointerException. It appears that AbstractPersistable_id is not being set, but I cannot figure out why or how I would go about setting it.

I have tried to match my implementation with the classes consumed by the [example tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/commit/84314e279e2bc3bb9e87f7bcd5b186545083f3bd#diff-8448b2fae7b1b7056b776705e5059aeeR335) in the spring-data-jpa repository. No good. I have also tried downloading the spring-data-jpa library to debug through their test case, but even checking out a tag with a clean workspace I can't for the life of me get the spring project's tests to compile and run. This may point to a Works On My Device issue, but I have reproduced my existsBy() issue on two other machines: one windows 7 and one linux. I'm starting to wonder if it might be a bug in hibernate or another one of my dependencies.

I also know that when I test entities that do not have a compound primary key, the existsBy() projection test compiles and runs fine, likely because the code does not pass through the fork of JpaQueryCreator.complete() that references AbstractPersistable_id. I can also add projections other than existsBy such as countBy() to a repository for entities with compound primary keys and it will compile fine. It is only the combination of existsBy() and a @IdClass compound primary key that causes the problem.

Version info: this repo is using Hibernate 5.1.0.Final ORM, hibernate jpa 2.1, spring-data-jpa 1.11.3, and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.5.3.RELEASE.

[Github example project](https://github.com/Lwiczyn/JPADATA-920-Issue)

The entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;

import com.example.exists.bug.entities.TestEntity.TestEntityPK;

@Entity
@IdClass(TestEntityPK.class)
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    private String parent;

    @Id
    private String child;

    // Getters, setters, hash, equals, toString

    protected final static class TestEntityPK implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String parent;

        private String child;

        TestEntityPK() {

        }

        public TestEntityPK(String parent, String child) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.child = child;
        }

        //ToString, hash, equals
    }
```

The repository:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.exists.bug.entities.TestEntity;

@Repository
public interface TestEntityRepository
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TestEntity, Serializable>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<TestEntity> {

    boolean existsByParent(String parent);
}
```

The test case:

```
package com.example.exists.bug;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable_;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.example.exists.bug.repository.TestEntityRepository;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest(showSql = false)
public class TestEntityRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityRepository testEntityRepository;

    @Test
    public void existsByParentCausesApplicationSetupToFailWithNullPointerException() {
        testEntityRepository.existsByParent("parent");
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testEntityRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:187) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:52) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:126) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:70) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have the same problem with that sh*t but for me it ends with the following exception `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property existsByXxx found for type Xxx!`

Comment: These are two different issues. I filed a [bug report](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1130).

Comment: @mp911de Thank you for getting to the bottom of this. Would it be appropriate to create an answer marking this as a bug?